# Getting csharp-mode Emacs syntax highlighting working

Tags: c#, emacs, mono, elisp

Googling "csharp mode emacs" yields the page

> http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CSharpMode

which includes a few links to various downloadable emacs lisp files. The 2005 link (DylanMoonfire) is broken, so I downloaded:

> http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2002-May/006182.html

as ~/.emacslib/csharp-mode.el

and added:

```
(autoload 'csharp-mode "csharp-mode"
  "Major mode for editing C# code." t)
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '( "\\.cs\\'" . csharp-mode ) auto-mode-alist ))
```

to my .emacs file (anywhere, beginning, middle or end). I attempt to edit a new text file called "t.cs" and I get the error:

> File mode specification error: (error "Buffer t.cs is not a CC Mode buffer (c-set-style)")

and no syntax highlighting. I'm not well versed in emacs-lisp but I know enough to install support for loads of language modes and csharp-mode is just not playing nice compared to every other language mode I've installed.

I was getting excited to play with Mono on my Mac and ran into this ridiculous barrier! Anyone out there know how to get decent support for C# syntax highlighting in emacs?

Note: I'm using a MacBook Pro running Emacs 22.1.1 on OS X Leopard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a more recent version of csharp-mode [0.7.0](http://trac.codecheck.in/share/browser/dotfiles/emacs/k1low/.emacs.d/elisp/nxhtml/related/csharp-mode.el), go to the end of the page and download as plain text. Haven't tried loading the mode however.

Just uploaded the code to emacswiki as well: [charp-mode.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/csharp-mode.el)

Comment: This is the one I use. (and I get syntax highlighting)

Comment: Thanks for updating that page for future users. Thanks for the reminded to download as plain text, with that weird ^L in there.

Comment: FYI Csharp-mode.el is now v0.7.2. Still available at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/csharp-mode.el . It's improved in various ways, includes more reliable indenting, better fontification, and automatic xml code doc templating. No code-completion ("intellisense") ... yet?

Comment: I am using a portable version of emacs 24.3 on windows. how can i install this? I am new to emacs.

Answer (score 1):

What you have seems to be very outdated.  It's too bad that the more up-to-date version was not hosted somewhere safer, like the Emacs core, EmacsWiki, or Github.

But anyway, you might as well try asking on #emacs (Freenode) and see if someone can send you the more up-to-date file.

Comment: Now hosted where it belongs, on EmacsWiki (care of danielpoe).

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight modification to make Tab indent 4 spaces and deal with braces correctly, so now hitting tab on any line "does the right thing" with respect to conventions in Visual Studio.

http://www.updike.org/files/csharp-mode.el

Answer (score 0):

The EmacsWiki page for [CSharpMode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CSharpMode) says that *the most current version of this package can always be found on github* ([josteink/csharp-mode](https://github.com/josteink/csharp-mode)).

Maybe you would like to use [OmniSharp-Emacs](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-emacs) that *provides IDE-like features for editing files in C# solutions in Emacs*.

See also the article [Emacs as a C# development environment](https://joshwolfe.ca/post/emacs-for-csharp/).